# How to place a Xul window as "Always On Top"?

Tags: javascript, xul, xpcom, always-on-top

I found [this file](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Fq9H1krZ5o0/trunk/chrome/lous_jar/content/lous.xul&q=%22always%20on%20top%22%20lang%3axul&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=1144) at google code with the function:

```
function SetAlwaysOnTop() {
    var chkTop = document.getElementById("itmAlwaysOnTop");
    var xulWin = window.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
        .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
        .treeOwner.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
        .getInterface(Ci.nsIXULWindow);
    if(chkTop.getAttribute("checked") == "true") {
        xulWin.zLevel = xulWin.raisedZ;
    } else {
        xulWin.zLevel = xulWin.normalZ;
    }
}
```

The parts of it that I need are just:

```
var xulWin = window.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
        .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
        .treeOwner.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
        .getInterface(Ci.nsIXULWindow);
xulWin.zLevel = xulWin.raisedZ;
```

But I'm not finding what where's the Ci defined. Any idea what can it be? Or any other idea of how to set a window always on top? (that solution "just for windows" don't fits to me).

**--update**

I'm reading about the [nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWindowMediator), which has some methods to handle the window Z order. But it's saying that the methods should be used from c++, not javascript. That means the code should be used from XPCOM components (I should as XPCOM component to open the window)? Does anyone that already used it could confirm?

I'm still reading anyway.

**--update**

I've tried the nsIWindowMediator (with a XPCOM component) but it just does nothing when I set the Z level.

Still look for a way to put the window aways on top..

**--attempt with 'alwaysraised':**

test.xul:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    onload="open('top.xul','GreenfoxChannelWindow','chrome, alwaysraised');"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="MAIN WINDOW"/>

</window>
```

top.xul:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="ON TOP"/>

</window>
```

didn't worked.

**--attempt with 'zlevel':**

test.xul:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    onload="open('top.xul','GreenfoxChannelWindow','chrome');"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="MAIN WINDOW"/>

</window>
```

top.xul:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300" zlevel="6"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="ON TOP"/>

</window>
```

didn't worked. Nither with alwaysraised setted, or adding a higher or lower zlevel to the test.xul (with top.xul zlevel="6")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found: just open it using openDialog, and it will be always on top.

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    onload="openDialog('top.xul','TopWindow','chrome');"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="MAIN WINDOW"/>

</window>
```

top.xul:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="ON TOP" />

</window>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how to use openDialog to open a window in this manner and also include a link to the resource where you found this.  Thanks for answering your own question :)

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with opening the window as always on top.

Comment: @Neil if you run it, you can see that the window with the label "ON TOP" will never be behind any other window. Just what I wanted..

Comment: I never would have thought that would work in a million years.  Thanks for clarifying @Neil's question and posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want the window to be on top, then the easiest way is to use the `alwaysraised` chrome flag when opening the window.

If you don't get to open the window yourself, the second easiest way is to use `<window zlevel="6">` in your XUL. You can even persist the zlevel; SeaMonkey's Help window does this, using a context menu option to toggle the zLevel.

By the way, `Ci` is a common abbreviation for `Components.interfaces` since writing (e.g.) `Components.interfaces.nsIXULWindow.rasiedZ` is difficult to do on 80-character lines.

Comment: I tried alwaysraised and zlevel, but none work. I've updated the question with my samples.

Comment: found: using openDilaog is the way to go.. :)

Comment: `alwaysRaised` or `alwaysraised` work for me in the latest Firefox version (26.0 as of this writing).