# How to make a Xul window get all input from another window?

Tags: events, xul

I've thought about listen to the keypress and mouse events from the other window, but I don't know how to generate this event to my listener window.

Any idea how can I forward key and mouse events from a window to another?

--**update**

To change the focus of the current window would be an option. But it just don't work with `onload="opener.focus();"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could set up functions in the child window and call functions in the parent window via [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener).  I guess in some way or another, you need to call a function in the parent, that seems like the simplest way.

Comment: I guess so, but I don't know how to generate the keyboard and mouse inputs for the opener window. I just found the keypress function, but I don't think is the correct way.. Also it didn't worked calling it with the arguments[0] parameter from the child window's keypress event.

Comment: Do you want the inputs from the child window or the parent window?

Comment: I'm suggesting you set up events in the child window, add functions in the child window to handle the events, and then call a function in the parent window via window.opener.funcName(myEventData)

Comment: I want the inputs from the child window go to the opener window. Like if the child window was just a "tooltip box", with no focus, and getting no input. (and yes, it need to be a window)

Comment: Please, add @Tom Brito when answering, so I see your answer in my summary.. :)

Comment: @Tom Brito, I still don't follow what about my suggestion does not work.  Do you actually need to trigger an event in the parent window; is it not sufficient to simply call a function in the parent window?

Comment: I had no success calling it from the opener, but with a event listener to the keypress event it worked nice.. now I have still a problem with the focus, but that's another question, so I'll open a new thread.. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes, I already had one (if you can help): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335286/how-to-place-a-xul-window-as-always-on-top

Comment: I see.  Maybe i wasn't clear enough, but I mean that you would set up a traditional event (I was assuming you already had this or could do it) and then from the event handler, call window.opener.someFunction and pass the data to the parent that way.